# Как правильно проверить на null

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, почему не работает проверка на null, приложение просто крашится.

```
package com.veboro.cvkom;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Gaz extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gaz);
    }

    public void gaz (View view){
        EditText pop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pop);
        EditText tep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tep);
        TextView summa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Double popFin = Double.parseDouble(pop.getText().toString());
        Double tepFin = Double.parseDouble(tep.getText().toString());

        if (popFin == null || tepFin == 0){
            summa.setText("Всі поля обовязкові для заповнення");
        } else {
            double result = (tepFin - popFin) * 6.87;
            summa.setText("До сплати " + String.format("%.2f", result) + " грн.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: С какой ошибкой крашится? Добавьте в вопрос её полный текст.

Comment: Просто перезагружается, в логах нет прямых ошибок.

Comment: тогда как вы определили, что виновата проверка на null?

Comment: Если поля пусты то после нажатия кнопки все перезагружается, в ином случае все работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас очень странный код. Во-первых, [EditText.getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) для пустого поля вернёт "". При попытке вызывать [Double.parseDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) с пустой строкой возникнет исключение [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). Что у вас скорее всего и происходит. Но вы его перехватывать не пытаетесь, а вместо этого проверяете переменную `popFin` на `null`, которого там никак оказаться не может. Попробуйте так:

```
    EditText pop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pop);
    EditText tep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tep);
    TextView summa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String popFinVal = pop.getText().toString();
    String tepFinVal = tep.getText().toString();

    if (popFinVal.isEmpty() || tepFinVal.isEmpty()) {
        summa.setText("Всі поля обовязкові для заповнення");
    }
    else {
        try {
            double popFin = Double.parseDouble(popFinVal);
            double tepFin = Double.parseDouble(tepFinVal);

            double result = (tepFin - popFin) * 6.87;
            summa.setText(String.format("До сплати %.2f грн.", result));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException exc) {
            summa.setText("Невірний формат");
        }
    }
```